# Usage of ~ symbol in append statement

Tags: java

I have a StringBuilder variable strbuff which is as below:

```
strBuff.append("~").append(rs.getString(1)).append("~,")
            .append(rs.getInt(2)).append("~~");
```

What is the meaning of using `~`?

I don't think it is acting as bitwise operator in this scenario.

Note: the strBuff returns a string statement to a .groovy class.

Comment: @KevinEsche yes. my mistake. It is a StringBuffer.

Comment: @KevinEsche so it doesn't have any usage?

Comment: *"What is the meaning of using `~`?"* Nothing. They are just characters inserted into the string. Whether they have meaning later on depends entirely on *how* you're using that string later on. That code is logically the same as `strBuff.append("~" + rs.getString(1) + "~," + rs.getInt(2) + "~~")`. It's just building a string with `~` characters in it.

Comment: @user7324003 what Andreas said, it depends on your program and what it´s going to do with whatever is getting build there.

Answer (score 0):

`~` this symbol is not a opertor,It is simply used to split/concat the string because it doesn't have special meaning like `-,/,%` these operators.

e.g

```
String fruits= "Apple~Banana";
String[] fruit= string.split("~");
```

Note- we can also used for `~` symbol for StringBuilder and StringBuffer

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. I thought that "~" had a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting together a comma-separated-values line. "~" is probably being used as an uncommon character for later replacement with a single or double quote, probably after escaping all existing quotes in the strBuf. Something like

```
String result = strBuf.toString().replace("'", "''").replace("~", "'")
```

In other words, it isn't being used as an operator, but it is being used as a magic constant.